# How to delete broken file references on external drive?

Tags: linux

On Lubuntu 14.04, when I do a listing in the directory of a FAT32 mounted external disk, about half the files are not accessible.  when I try to remove one of the files, I get

```
rm: cannot remove myfile.txt: Input/output error
```

How can I cleanup the directory and delete these erroneous file references?

Comment: Have you run `fsck`?

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully, I dont know the right syntax

Comment: unmount the drive and then `fsck [device-name]`

Comment: Also keep in mind that your external disk is potentially damaged. If you don't have a backup of those files, and you value the contents, **don't do any write operations** like trying to remove files. Make a backup of the good files (or the whole disk) first.

Comment: Agree with @dirkt. Use fsck's `-n` option (or answer 'no' to any questions `fsck` asks) to avoid writing over a potentially bad drive. If possible, use `dd` to image the drive first and make sure the image is the same size as the drive.